# Using SDM(Spatial Data Modeller) toolbox in ArcGIs9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, fuzzy-logic

I want to use fuzzy logic method to mapping in ArcGIS9.3, but I don't have any knowledge about that.Please guide me in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very general. If you want to know know to how apply Fuzzy logic in ArcGIS, ESRI provided a good explanation on how to [Applying fuzzy logic to overlay rasters](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/applying-fuzzy-logic-to-overlay-rasters.htm). The explanation in the help provides logical steps on how to use Fuzzy logic. Although it is written for ArcGIS 10.3 and 10.4, but it can be applied in 9.3 if you have Spatial Analyst extension.